# duvida sobre git no fetch e push

Tags: git

1. No diretório do projeto local inicie o controle de versão do git:
   git init
2. Insira todos os arquivos do projeto no controle de versão do git:
   git add .
3. Faça o commit do projeto:
   git commit -m "descrição breve do commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/weldermartins/Financeiro.git

git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/weldermartins/Financeiro.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/weldermartins/Financeiro.git (push)

o projeto sobe, mas a pasta fica inacessível como uma seta branca para a direta.
git push -u origin master

Comment: Essa pasta parece que foi adicionada como submodule no repositório local

Comment: entra na pasta e veja se ela não tem um .git oculto tb, se tiver, acredito eu que deletando o .git e dando push novamente vá corrigir

Comment: Boa tarde pessoal, realmente era isso mesmo, dentro da pasta do projeto havia .git porém era do heroku, então fiz uma copia do projeto e apaguei o .git, estava ficando sem entender. 
obrigado